# Is Bluetooth transmitter/receiver fine for connecting mouse/keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth

I want to buy [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000117330187.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.17bc2d29V2xpr0&algo_pvid=d5b5eb99-4117-40ce-a1ad-4ab594c055c2&algo_expid=d5b5eb99-4117-40ce-a1ad-4ab594c055c2-43&btsid=556ef4d1-7ee7-448e-bd38-5fc3c5dde510&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3,searchweb201603_53) transmitter/receiver but in specifications I see everything about audio only. Can I use it with my PC to connect keyboard or mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information and drawings on the link you've provided, it appears that the USB port is supplying power and very likely power only. The double-ended cables provide for audio source/destination for the bluetooth aspect of the device.

This means the answer to your question is quite likely NO.

A quick search discovers a product available that explicitly presents as mouse/keyboard capable:

[eBay link for example](https://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Bluetooth-5-0-Adapter-Drive-Desktop-Computer-Dongle-Transceiver-Music-Audio-/293148378343?_trksid=p2385738.m4383.l4275.c10)

[image: ebay photo]

Comment: Thank you, do you have any ideas how should I search for adapter which is able to connect mouse/keyboard? How they are called? I want USB 5.0.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same.